# Why does Excel give me incorrectly rounded numbers when I didn't specify rounding?

Tags: microsoft-excel

This seems very simple to me,

```
Cell A1: 1100.00
Cell B1: 200.00
Cell C1: =Quotient(A1,B1)
```

- Answer given by Excel: 5.00
- Real answer: 5.5

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because [`QUOTIENT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/QUOTIENT-function-9f7bf099-2a18-4282-8fa4-65290cc99dee)

> returns the integer portion of a division. Use this function when you want to discard the remainder of a division.

I.e. it's an integer division like `/` in C, C++ or Java

> If you want to divide numeric values, you should use the "/" operator as there isn't a DIVIDE function in Excel. For example, to divide 5 by 2, you would type **=5/2** into a cell, which returns 2.5. The QUOTIENT function for these same numbers **=QUOTIENT(5,2)** returns 2, since QUOTIENT doesn't return a remainder. For other ways to divide numbers, see [Multiply and divide numbers](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/multiply-and-divide-numbers-in-excel-4585b0ea-0ea0-4faf-84e4-3db5d4b2dc5d).

Comment: Thank you very much.  When searching for function "division" the only option that came up was Quotient.  I appreciate your time!

Comment: if you want division why don't just use division operator `/`? No need to search.